# Spectrum: Boundary

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

**Problem**

Given a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$.

Denote for readability:
$$\Omega\subseteq\mathbb{C}:\quad\|\Omega\|:=\|\omega\|_{\omega\in\Omega}:=\sup_{\omega\in\Omega}|\omega|$$

Denote for shorthand:
$$\Omega\subseteq\mathbb{R}:\quad\Omega_+:=\sup_{\omega\in\Omega}\omega\quad \Omega_-:=\inf_{\omega\in\Omega}\omega$$

For bounded operators:
$$A\in\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H}):\quad\sigma(A)\subseteq\overline{\mathcal{W}(A)}$$

For normal operators:
$$N^*N=NN^*:\quad\|\sigma(N)\|=\|\mathcal{W}(N)\|$$

> But one has even:
>   $$H=H^*:\quad\sigma(H)_\pm=\mathcal{W}(H)_\pm$$

How can I prove this?

**Attempt**

The argument goes as:
$$|\langle N\hat{\varphi},\hat{\varphi}\rangle|\leq\|N\|\cdot\|\hat{\varphi}\|^2=\|\sigma(N)\|$$
*(It exploits normality!)*

**Example**

As standard example:
$$\left\langle\sigma\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}\right\rangle=(0)\quad\overline{\mathcal{W}\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}}=\tfrac12\mathbb{D}$$

*(It exploits nilpotence!)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $H=H^{\star}$ be a bounded selfadjoint operator and let $\rho=\inf_{\|x\|=1}(Hx,x)$. Then $\rho_{\epsilon}(x,y)=((H-\rho I+\epsilon I)x,y)$ is an inner product on $\mathcal{H}$ for any $\epsilon > 0$. So,
$$
       |\rho_{\epsilon}(x,y)| \le \rho_{\epsilon}(x,x)^{1/2}\rho_{\epsilon}(y,y)^{1/2}.
$$
Letting $\epsilon \downarrow 0$ gives
$$
       |((H-\rho I)x,y)| \le ((H-\rho I)x,x)^{1/2}((H-\rho I)y,y)^{1/2}.
$$
Let $y = (H-\rho I)x$ in order to obtain
\begin{align}
     \|(H-\rho I)x\|^{2} & \le ((H-\rho I)x,x)^{1/2}((H-\rho I)(H-\rho I)x,(H-\rho I)x)^{1/2} \\
       & \le ((H-\rho I)x,x)^{1/2}\|H-\rho I\|^{1/2}\|(H-\rho I)x\|
\end{align}
Hence,
$$
    \|(H-\rho I)x\| \le \|H-\rho I\|^{1/2}((H-\rho I)x,x)^{1/2}.
$$
By the definition of $\rho$, there is a sequence of unit vectors $\{ x_{n} \}$ such that $((H-\rho I)x_{n},x_{n})\rightarrow 0$. Therefore,
$$
                \lim_{n}\|(H-\rho I)x_{n} \|=0,
$$
which means $\rho \in \sigma(H)$ because it is in the point spectrum or approximate point spectrum of $H$. By the way, you also see that a unit vector $x$ minimizes $(Hx,x)$ over all unit vectors iff $Hx = \rho x$.

The opposite direction is not so difficult, which is to say that every $\rho'$ such that $\rho ' < \rho=\inf_{\|x\|=1}(Hx,x)$ is in the resolvent of $H$. I've shown that to you before.

Comment: Man I must admit again and again: You're really awesome!!! :D

Comment: I found an *extremely* elementary proof. xD *(See my answer.)*

Comment: @Freeze_S : You are assuming facts I'm proving from scratch. The assumption $\|\sigma(N)\|=\|\mathcal{W}(N)\|$ is what I've proved here for selfadjoint, and I proved $\mathcal{W}(H)_{\pm}=\sigma(H)_{\pm}$. My assumptions: $H=H^{\star}$ and the CS inequality.

Comment: But that really is a one-liner: I didn't assume it but proved in the question above. *(See 'Attempt'.)*

Comment: The only thing I really *secretly* assumed is the spectral radius formula for Banach algebras: $r(A)=\limsup_n\|A^n\|^{1/n}$

Comment: @Freeze_S : What is a one-liner? $r_{\sigma}(H)=\|H\|$ is non-trivial compared to CS. $|(Nx,x)| \le \|N\|=r_{\sigma}(N)$ for unit vectors gives $\|\mathcal{W}(N)\|\le \|\sigma(N)\|$. What other facts are you then using to get the opposite inequality? It's a useful exercise to examine the assumptions.

Comment: From $\sigma(A)\leq\overline{\mathcal{W}(A)}$ it follows $\|\sigma(A)\|\leq\|\mathcal{W}(A)\|$. *(That is: "The opposite direction is not so difficult...")*

Comment: That is basic C*-property: $r_\sigma(H)=\lim_n\|H^n\|^{1/n}=\lim_k\|H^{2^k}\|^{1/2^k}=\lim_k\|H\|=\|H\|$

Comment: @Freeze_S : It's at a much higher level than Cauchy-Schwarz. :)

Comment: Ya kind of true - you got me. ^^

Comment: I just noticed: In fact, sesquilinear forms are already hidden in that: $\sigma(A)\subseteq\overline{\mathcal{W}(A)}$

Answer (score 0):

Define the value:
$$\omega:=\omega_-:=\mathcal{W}(H)_-$$

By linearity of range:
$$\mathcal{W}(H-\omega)=\mathcal{W}(H)-\omega\geq0$$

For bounded operators:
$$\mathcal{W}(H-\omega)\geq0\implies\sigma(H-\omega)\geq0$$

For normal operators:
$$\sigma(H-\omega)_+=\|\sigma(H-\omega)\|=\|\mathcal{W}(H-\omega)\|=\mathcal{W}(H-\omega)_+$$

By linearity of both:
$$\sigma(H)_+=\sigma(H-\omega)_++\omega=\mathcal{W}(H-\omega)_++\omega=\mathcal{W}(H)_+$$
$$\sigma(H)_-=-\sigma(-H)_+=-\mathcal{W}(-H)_+=\mathcal{W}(H)_-$$

Concluding the assertion.